# How I can print the start and end dates of a data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have these lines of code, and when I run it, I would like to see the dates of training, validation and test like this:

```
2012-01-01 00:00:00 --- 2013-12-31 23:00:00:00
```

instead of the indices:

```
20150 --- 20189
```

```py
datos = df_energy.loc['2015-07-02 01:00:00': '2021-11-30 15:00:00']

fin_train = '2019-12-31 23:59:00'
fin_validacion = '2020-11-30 23:59:00'

datos_train = datos.loc[:fin_train, :]
datos_val   = datos.loc[fin_train: fin_validacion, :]
datos_test  = datos.loc[fin_validacion:, :]

print(f"Fechas train      : {datos_train.index.min()} --- {datos_train.index.max()}")
print(f"Fechas validacion : {datos_val.index.min()} --- {datos_val.index.max()}")
print(f"Fechas test       : {datos_test.index.min()} --- {datos_test.index.max()}")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the indxes, just use them for getting the related value. I will do that for the train data exemplary, you can then just transfer it equally to the other datasets:

```
def gen_timerange(df, col='UTC Time'):
    min_time = df.loc[df.index.min(), col]
    max_time = df.loc[df.index.max(), col]
    return f"{min_time} --- {max_time}"

print(f"Fechas train      : {gen_timerange(datos_train)}")
```